# Nucleo STM32F103RB Cannot Get Drivers To Work To Enable LED

Tags: stm32

So I am getting into STM32 and I decided that it would be great if I started by developing my own drivers to enable all the registers and such. When I try to test my GPIO register it seems that it does not work. I tried to debug for a while and I fixed all the issues that I could find and it would not work. I made sure that I enabled the peripheral clocks and changed the GPIOx_CRL register to make sure that every register configures correctly but it seems like when I plug my led into the pin that is labelled D2 and run my code nothing happens when I can see that the registers were confgiured properly.

Here is my main.c

```
#include "stm32f103rb.h"

void delay (void)
{
    for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i<500;i++);
}

int main(void)
{
    GPIO_Handle_t GpioLed;

    GpioLed.pGPIOx = GPIOD;
    GpioLed.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber = GPIO_PIN_NO_2;
    GpioLed.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinMode = GPIO_MODE_OUT10;
    GpioLed.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinOutMode = GPIO_OP_TYPE_PP;
    GpioLed.GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinPuPdControl = PULLDOWN;

    GPIO_PeriClockControl(GPIOD,ENABLE);

    /*pAPB2ENR |= (1<<5); */


    GPIO_Init(&GpioLed);

    while(1)
    {
        GPIO_ToggleOutputPin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_NO_2);
        delay();
    }

    return 0;
```

everything seems to work up until my  GPIO_ToggleOutputPin, when I run that code block which is:

```
void GPIO_ToggleOutputPin(GPIO_RegDef_t *pGPIOx, uint8_t PinNumber)
{
    pGPIOx->ODR ^= (1 << PinNumber);
}
```

I can see that the ODR register changes my ODR2 value to 1 in the register but my led is not turning on. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I tried to debug by making sure all the registers were configuring correctly which they are but my led isnt turning on.

Comment: Are you using a current-limiting resistor in series with your LED? If not, you've probably burned out the LED and/or the GPIO pin.

Answer (score 0):

Pin `D2` on Nucleo F103RB board is the Arduino pin based on Arduino naming notation, it is actually PA10 (Port A, Pin 10), it is not Port D, Pin 2 that you are configuration code is doing. If you connected your LED to `D2`, you need to configure the Port A, Pin 10, or alternatively, using your existing code but connect the LED to PD2 on the upper left corner of the board.

See the Figure 14. NUCLEO-F103RB from [STM32 Nucleo-64 Boards User Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1724-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

[image]